# Template function specialization default

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make a class which will work with specific data types and I want to have a compile-time error when data type is not supported.

I tried to specialize templates like this.

```
template<>
float Foo::get<float>(const std::string& key)
{
    return std::stof(key);
}
```

And put a `std::static_assert` in the generic function because I only need these types that are specified.

```
template<class T>
T Foo::get(const std::string&)
{
    static_assert(false, "unsupported data type");
    return T(0);
}
```

Unfortunately I get the compile error (static assert failed) even if I have a specialized function for this type.

I found a way to do it for the specific types only but it looks kinda stupid and its not generic.

```
T Foo::get(const std::string&)
{
    static_assert(
            std::is_same<T,float>::value ||
            std::is_same<T,double>::value ||
            std::is_same<T,bool>::value ||
            std::is_same<T,uint32_t>::value ||
            std::is_same<T,int32_t>::value ||
            std::is_same<T,std::string>::value,
            "unsuported data type");
    return T(0);
}
```

Comment: There's fancy trick (`always_false<T>::value`) for that purpose, but I think it's simpler to just not define the primary template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `static_assert` depending on the template parameter `T`, then it won't be evaluated until the time of instantiation, i.e. the time the exact type is explored as template argument. e.g.

```
template<class T>
T get(const std::string&)
{
    static_assert(!std::is_same<T, T>::value, "unsupported data type");
    return T(0);
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uaG0josotMm0ifaa)

Comment: I prefer the `static_assert(sizeof(T) == -1, "unsupported data type");` for being more compact. Also i believe this is the more common approach.

Comment: I found and tried this but it is still giving me this compile time errors.
Where should be my specialized functions in the .cpp or in the header.
Does that even matter?

Comment: @PetarVelev It matters indeed. At least a declaration for the explicit specialisation must be visible at the point where it's used, or the compiler will instantiate an implicit specialisation from the primary template (which will give the error).

Comment: It should work. See here: https://ideone.com/RVH3ML

Comment: @Angew I thought that the problem might be something like this.
But if I the function logic in the header i get weird errors like this 
`.....h:75: multiple definition of 'bool... `

Comment: @PetarVelev A template specialisation is not a template, and thus follows normal function definition rules. If you want to put it in a header, it has to be marked `inline`.

Comment: I am tempted to close as duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078818/static-assert-dependent-on-non-type-template-parameter-different-behavior-on-gc which contradicts your answer. Any thoughts?

Comment: @K.Kirsz: for `static_assert(sizeof(T) == -1`, you cannot then have valid instantiation, so the program is technically ill formed. `std::is_same<T, T>::value` can be specialized to have valid `get`.

Comment: @Angew Thank you! Your last comment helped me.

Comment: [This code is ill formed with no diagnostic required.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44848147/4899740)

Answer (score 1):

You may do

```
template <typename> struct AlwaysFalse : false_type {};


template<class T>
T Foo::get(const std::string&)
{
    static_assert(AlwaysFalse<T>::value, "unsupported data type");
}
```

So the assert is template dependent.

Comment: I am tempted to close as duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078818/static-assert-dependent-on-non-type-template-parameter-different-behavior-on-gc which contradicts your answer. Any thoughts?

Comment: @bolov: It doesn't contradict my answer. `AlwaysFalse<T>::value` **is** dependent of `T`. And we might construct `dummy` class and specialize `struct AlwaysFalse<dummy> : true_type {};` to have a valid instantiation of `Foo::get<T>`.

Comment: well.. there's that quote: "Inside a template, some constructs have semantics which may differ from one instantiation to another. Such a construct depends on the template parameters."

Comment: @bolov:`AlwaysFalse<T>::value` depend of `T`, it could have different value (as with my specialization with `dummy`). ON the contrary,`false` cannot change value depending of `T`.